# How to remove autospace between elements in xml?

Tags: css, xml

There's an xml document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="#style" type="text/css"?>
<root>
  <style>
    style {display: none}
    entry {display: block}
    english {font-weight: bold} 
    spanish {font-style: italic}  
  </style>
  <entry>
    <sense_unit>
      <english>abandon</english>
      <spanish>abandonar</spanish>
    </sense_unit>, 
    <sense_unit>
      <english>friend</english>
      <spanish>amigo</spanish>
    </sense_unit>
  </entry>
</root>
```

Web browser renders this:

```
style {display: none} entry {display: block} english {font-size: 10pt; font-family:    "Times New Roman"} spanish {font-size: 9pt; font-family: "Arial"} 
abandon abandonar , friend amigo
```

1. I'd like to hide the contents of style element, but it still appears.
2. I don't want the space between abandonar and the following comma. (But I don't want to insert the comma inside the sense_unit) How can I do that? (That is, ... abandonar , friend ... -> ... abandonar, friend ...)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with css, and everything to do with well-formed XML.  All linebreaks in XML are considered an element and therefore will create those spaces.  Remove all your line-breaks and those spaces will disappear.

Update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsMUW/) example where I've removed all your line breaks and spaces just within the `<entry>`